# Handling users and groups in ExtJS

Tags: extjs

I would like to try to use ExtJs for a new web app.
I need to handle users and roles to give different app features according to the connected user's role. Are there native or pre-built libraries to do this (as, for example in Drupal) or should i create it from scratch?

Answer (score 6):

Build your own.  Consult the following URL:

http://technopaper.blogspot.com/2010/02/access-control-in-extjs-applications.html

Particularly the first sentence of the second paragraph:

"Permissions should be always be implemented on server side and JavaScript security is always secondary"

Remember, ExtJS is a client side, Javascript-based framework.  Therefore comparisons with server side frameworks such as Drupal are not valid.

I found the URL above by googling for "extjs access control".  You might cast a wider net Javascript-wise by replacing ExtJS with jQuery, though my cursory examination of the results leads me to believe that you will not find much useful.